# Break in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

**My code is below in Laravel 5.1**

```
@foreach($Project->ProjectSkills as $ProjectSkill)
    @if($Skill->SkillID == $ProjectSkill->SkillID)
        <option selected value="{{$Skill->SkillID}}">{{$Skill->Skill}}</option>
    @else
        <option value="{{$Skill->SkillID}}">{{$Skill->Skill}}</option>
    @endif
    @break;
@endforeach
```

**Can somebody tell why break is not working ?**

Comment: Because it's not implemented, no? You can implement your own `@break` though, with something like `Blade::directive('break', function() {             return "<?php break; ?>"; });`

Comment: `@break;` is present above `@endforeach`

Comment: What raina77ow meant was `@break` is not provided as a pre-defined directive in laravel's blade templates. You can extend blade to define it. [More info](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#extending-blade)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `boot` method of AppServiceProvider class in app/Providers, you can define a directive like this:

```
public function boot()
{
    Blade::directive('break', function() { return "<?php break; ?>"; });
}
```

Don't forget to write `use Blade;` below the namespace decalaration.